# Django: Return all Values even if filtering through a related model

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Thanks to some fantastic help on a previous question I have managed to put together my query.  Everything works swimmingly save one issue.

```
    careers = Career.objects.filter(job__dwarf__user = 1).annotate(dwarves_in_career = Count('job__dwarf'))
```

In my view this does exactly what I want and when I loop it in my template like so:

```
{% for career in careers reversed %}
    <li>{{ career.name }}: {{ career.dwarves_in_career }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I get what I expected.  My issue is that the above code will only return the Careers that have dwarves.  I need it to return *all* careers:

```
Unassigned: 1
Construction: 1
Crafting: 2
Gathering: 0
Farming: 0
```

is my expected results.  Instead the last two rows are not there because I am filtering for the specific user.  I know why it's happening, what I am trying to figure out is how to get the query to return all careers, even if their dwarf count for a particular user is 0.

Comment: +1 for `dwarves_in_career`. The mind boggles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I eventually figured it out...

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

def fortress(request):
    careers = Career.objects.filter(Q(job__dwarf__user = 1) | Q(job__dwarf__user__isnull = True)).annotate(dwarves_in_career = Count('job__dwarf'))
    return render_to_response('ragna_base/fortress.html', {'careers': careers})
```

Not *exactly* sure what Q is but it works!

More information here: http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/or_lookups/

Basically what I am doing is finding all careers with dwarves (based on user_id) OR all careers that have no dwarves (based on null)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to swap over your `annotate` and `filter` clauses. See [the documentation on this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) - the way you have it, it filters the *queryset*, but you actually want to keep the entire queryset but just filter the *annotations*.

Comment: I see where you are getting at but unfortunately this won't work.  The reason it isn't pulling my dwarfless careers is because they don't have the corresponding user_id.  I need a way to get the careers even if there are no dwarves in it.